Synchronization between IHostedService-s in ASP.NET Core app
I have an ASP.NET Core app with 2 background services implemented by using the IHostedService:
StartupService       // performs some action after app starts only once
TimerBasedService    // performs some action periodically 

What is the correct way to sync between them, i.e. action of TimerBasedService should be performed first time AFTER action by StartupService is done? Is using of synchronization objects
like lock or manual reset event correct here? Thanks in advance

You can create a synchronization mechanism, such as a boolean flag(by using ManualResetEventSlim), that indicates whether the action of StartupService has completed.
In the Startup or Program class, register StartupService first and ensure that it sets the flag indicating its completion. Then, register TimerBasedService, ensuring that it checks this flag before executing its action.
A simple demo:
public class StartupService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly ManualResetEventSlim _startupCompleted;

    public StartupService(ManualResetEventSlim startupCompleted)
    {
        _startupCompleted = startupCompleted;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Perform startup actions here
        _startupCompleted.Set(); // Signal that startup is completed
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class TimerBasedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ManualResetEventSlim _startupCompleted;
    private readonly Timer _timer;

    public TimerBasedService(ManualResetEventSlim startupCompleted)
    {
        _startupCompleted = startupCompleted;
        _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); 
    }

    private void DoWork(object state)
    {
        if (_startupCompleted.IsSet)
        {
            // do your stuff...
        }
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}

Program.cs:
var startupCompleted = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
builder.Services.AddSingleton(startupCompleted);
builder.Services.AddHostedService<StartupService>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<TimerBasedService>();

